# Jamaica: selecting the "Junction" route

Tags: driving, jamaica

I was advised to take the 'Junction' route from KIN to Port Antonio.

Is this the clockwise or counterclockwise, coastal route?

Are there tolls on this route and will they accept USD?

[image: Map]

If you have experience traversing either routes please state this in your response.  Arriving at 15:30 on a Friday and am open to advice.

Comment: Some good info on driving in Jamaica and specific toll roads:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g147309-i69-k9320360-Driving_from_Kingston_to_Ocho_Rios-Jamaica.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1z9vK3z2Ark) It sounds like "the Junction" is between St Andrew's and St Mary's parishes, which are both to the north and west of Kingston.  So it would seem that the inland route is the suggested one.

From what I can understand on the [Toll Authority](http://tollauthority.gov.jm/index.html) website, [the only toll roads](http://tollauthority.gov.jm/description.html) in Jamaica are not where you are going.

Comment: @pnuts It's going to take a local to sort all that out.

Comment: @pnuts I was referring to the "Google maps thinks .." part of your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is the clockwise route. There are no tolls on this route.
Condition of parts of this route is very sub standard.